Cannot open source file. No such file or directory when using generator expression
In CMake for my project I have the following:
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    message("Using GCC compiler")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
    message("Using Clang compiler")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
    message("Using MSVC compiler")
    add_compile_options(
        /MP # MULTIPROCESSOR COMPILE 
        /Oi # ENABLE COMPILER INTRINSICS
        /utf-8
        $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/fsanitize=address /fsanitize=fuzzer> 
    ) 

else ()
    message("Unknown compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
endif ()

It generates fine, but in Visual Studio when I try to compile it gives the error:

Error C1083   Cannot open source file: '$<1:/fsanitize=address': No such
file or directory MyProject F:\$<1:\fsanitize=address   1

It's specifically that generator expression line that causes this. Why is this making the compiler look for a source file? Is the MyProject F:\$<1:\fsanitize=address 1   a clue?

In CMake a space is a delimiter of arguments. So effectively you pass $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/fsanitize=address as a 4th argument and /fsanitize=fuzzer> as the 5th. Note, that generator expressions are not part of the CMake syntax. When split content of CMakeLists.txt into tokens, $, < and > are treated as regular symbols.

So I can just do set(DEBUG_FLAGS /fsanitize=address /somethingelse /Somethingelse2) and then $<$CONFIG:DEBUG:DEBUG_FLAGS>
